# Ubuntu 11.10, replacing unity with gnome

Tags: gnome

Today I've decided to replace unity with gnome. I used the "gnome-session-fallback".
My question is: is a fallback safe/effective in the long run? I was told that I can actually use some commands and get rid of unity totally and replace it with gnome. Is it true that replacing means more available things (compared to a gnome fallback)?

I was wondering what the real difference is between a fallback and a new installation of gnome.

Comment: This question is confusing, what were you told that is different from this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/58172/how-to-revert-to-gnome-classic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu already comes with Gnome 3, don't get all confused. Unity is compiz plug in, the underlaying environment is Gnome 3. The Gnome *Shell* is the new implementation of the Gnome 3 GUI, it's made of the regular Gnome  session and the Fallback session.

Put simply Gnome Classic or Gnome Fallback Session, is the Gnome Shell without the "3D" greatness.

It is as effective as you get to work with it. Now, yes you can Uninstall Unity and just keep Gnome Shell or the use the Fallback session.

Now, I get lost when you ask if you get "more things available" more of what?.

Comment: You know, you can add Compiz to Gnome Classic to make it look good.  Then, you can use Awn dock, and with a bit of creativity, have more versatility, more features, and better-looking (IMO) because you can customize it a lot.  If they would keep this configuration, I'd be happy.

Answer (score 1):

There's a good howto here:
[Ubuntu 11.10 Oneiric: Remove Unity and use Gnome Classic by Default](http://linux-software-news-tutorials.blogspot.com/2011/10/ubuntu-1110-oneiric-remove-unity-and.html)
I'm not sure if it gives you *more available things*...

Comment: It does help, but it doesnt really answer my question. I was wondering what the real difference is between a fallback and a new installation of gnome.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can look at it like this:

What you had before is now gone.  Completely gone.  Gnome 3 is different (that's the one where you got all your apps and stuff at the top left corner, and you got to go there to get to anything, or hit the windows key).

Fallback session is different, too!  Its similar but instead of having an 'Administration' tab at top along with 'Places' and 'Applications', now there are just the two and most of the admin stuff you need, all of it really, are under applications.

So the fallback and new install are very different and also both are different from earlier versions.

Sorry to break it to you.  I myself am pretty pissed about it. But my fallback session is almost as good, if only I could have buttons in my file browser so I could switch from icons to list, then I would be happy.

Anyway, I am going back to 10.04 because 11.10 is too unstable for me. I don't know what the future will bring. I heard Mint will provide a 'classic' desktop, that might be where I go finally.

Frankly I am surprised that Shuttlesworth would finally treat users just like Gates used to.  And my reaction is pretty much the same, F you buddy. Just making a point.

Comment: Mint, so far, is far from classic, and far from usable to me.  I think they realize this, so it may improve.  I tried it, but came back to Ubuntu 11.10 with Gnome Classic, Compiz, Awn, and the Cardapio menu, which I'm getting to like a lot.  PS... learn the hotkeys for icons and list, they're really not that hard.  :)

Comment: Marty...I kinda find Compiz confusing and difficult to manage. I am using gnome tweak at the moment, but it is limited. Would you say that compiz is a useful tool?